# test case generator using java

Tags: java, prolog

I'm developing an 'Automatic test case generator' using java. The inputs for the java program will be fed by prolog program. If the input is for example an integer 2 then the java program should square the number and display it as output. In the same way if there are 3 integers the java program should accept one number at a time and display all results (i mean it should test each case).

Comment: This is without a doubt the weirdest question I've seen on SO. I'm not saying it's off topic (a little vague, but not off topic) but WOW this is weird.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an "input?"

Comment: It's phrased sort of like a homework assignment.  Be careful before throwing a bunch of code up.

Comment: i've done those assignments an year ago and i dont have any now.

Comment: All inputs (whether from a `Swing` applet or the console) are `Strings`. The program has to convert the strings into different object types to "test each case."

Comment: @fire so how can i write the java code that accepts one input at a time and generates the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, all inputs are `Strings` The program has to convert the strings into different object types to "test each case", such as in the following program.

```
import java.util.*;

public class CaseTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(" "); //separate entries with a space
        String input;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            input = sc.next();
            try {
                double num = Double.parseDouble(input);
                System.out.println("" + Math.pow(num, 2));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                //input was not a number so move to the next "test"
            }
            try {
                URL test = new URL(input);
                System.out.println("Valid URL");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                //input was not a valid URL so move to the next "test"
            }
            //put more tests here if you want
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Just in case you're confused, you don't always have to conduct tests with a `try` block. You can use `if` and `switch` blocks as well (i.e. `if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("dog")) //do something`)